# Mails to Slack Channel by Subject

Tags: email, slack

We're using the official Email app for Slack to forward mails to a Slack channel which works pretty fine.

But as we received multiple type of mails to one mail adress, we like to post those mails to different Slack channels, based on the subject (or maybe sender).

Is there a way to do it, maybe with an other 3rd party solution?

Comment: Check out the Slack App directory. There a few apps that can help you solve your problem:  https://slack.com/apps

Answer (score 1):

you can try [MailClark](https://mailclark.ai), the SlackBot to both receive and send emails directly from Slack. 
MailClark offers you the ability to sort your emails through different channels, based on the senders. As MailClark CEO, I'd be more than happy to tell you more about it!